# jar file is not opening in windows 8.1

Tags: java, windows, jar, windows-8.1

when i am trying to open .jar file it doesn't do anything.There isno issue about java installation because netbeans working perfectly fine and also updated on latest version of java. how can i resolve this issue?

Regards 
Kunal

Comment: Have you tried going to the command line and running the jar file to see if any errors are being thrown? Go to command prompt, and use the command `java -jar path/to/jar/file.jar` and see what errors come up in the command prompt.

Comment: when i am trying to run with cmd it gives error:Error: Unable to access jarfile

Comment: What command do have executed? Have you amended the path and the name of Jar file in Orina2005's example?

Comment: yes i provide proper path of jar file

Answer (score 0):

Your system cannot find the jdk path. To check whether system find the jdk path or not , open cmd and type

```
C:> java
```

this message will come if not find path:

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Then you have to set environment variable.
Go to windows search box and type environment variable.

1. Under System Variables, click New.
2. Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
3. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
4. Click OK.
5. Click Apply Changes.
   And then again open cmd and type same command "java"
   it will show description and then try to run jar file.

Comment: I don't believe so. If `java.exe` would not be on the path the exception would not be `Error: Unable to access jarfile ...` (which comes from the JVM).

Comment: i know how to set the path and if netbeans is running properly it means path is set. Please suggest some good options.

Comment: The netbeans automatically set the jdk path. And on the other hand if you run eclipse they will give error jdk path not found.Try to open cmd and type java.

Comment: bro i already typed that it is installed an set up the path properly